# Leaking Tub/Shower from the tub spout

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak

I have a Moen Posi Temp shower valve that was leaking from the handle.

I took apart the handle and replaced the Moen Posi Temp 1222 faucet cartridge with a OEM factory replacement.  The old cartridge was impossible to get out and ended up coming out in pieces.

Now the leak has stopped from the handle but the tub leaks from the tub spout with the handle in the off position only from the cold side.  I can’t get it to stop leaking without shutting the water off.

Is it likely the replacement cartridge is defective or is the issue something else?

Comment: Perhaps you did not get out all of the broken pieces?   Or the the cartridge and/or  the handle was installed in the wrong orientation.